# xdebug through a proxy layer: nginx > apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx, xdebug, reverse-proxy

Having trouble getting xdebug to work with our server environment which I'm trying to replicate on a Vagrant box and is apache listening on 8080 with an nginx front end server listening on 443 upstream proxy_passing / to 8080

Have tried almost all variations of xdebug.remote_* settings but xdebug log keeps saying:

```
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

Any ideas what else I could look at trying?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `xdebug.remote_host` to the actual vagrant IP and not localhost?